# Create a new conversion events in firebase the events are automatically closed in production app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

While Create a new conversion events in firebase Analytics the event was automatically closed in production app.

In Local app conversion events

[image: In Local app conversion events]

Production app conversion events

[image: Production]